# Relational database normalization

Tags: sql, database, normalization

I'm having issues normalizing [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnZcK.png) and it's really bothering me. I can see that the table is in first normal form but from there I'm stuck. My usual method is to find partial dependencies by checking for consistencies in each row in reference to a primary key. The problem with this table is both:

1. The first column only contains unique data and so it seems like it could be used as a primary key for the whole table. I've only ever normalized tables with a composite primary key but it seems pointless to do that here as the first column works fine as a primary key on its own.
2. There's no consistencies in the rows. The screens all have different movies which have different prices/dates etc. Only the customerID/customername are consistent.

I don't know if it's a proper technique but I thought about normalizing by referring to the deletion anomaly and organizing the tables so that if the session is deleted, the information about the branch is preserved. Using this I can get to something that resembles 3rd normal form but I don't think it's correct.

```
Session | Branch | Screen | Movie | Session   | Session | Customer | Customer
ID      | ID     | ID     | ID    | Date      | Price   | ID       | Name
SS01    | B1     | S1     | M1    | 3-May-16  |   12.50 | C1       | Chris Hemsworth
SS02    | B2     | S1     | M2    | 4-Jun-16  |   19.45 | C2       | Chris Evans
SS03    | B1     | S2     | M2    | 3-May-16  |   12.67 | C2       | Chris Evans
SS04    | B4     | S2     | M4    | 13-may-16 |   14.56 | C3       |Tom Hiddleston
SS05    | B3     | S2     | M5    | 23-may-16 |   14.56 | C2       | Chris Evans
SS06    | B3     | S1     | M5    | 3-Jun-16  |   16.32 | C1       | Chris Hemsworth
SS07    | B4     | S2     | M3    | 14-May-16 |   21.78 | C2       | Chris Evans
SS08    | B1     | S2     | M2    | 6-Jun-16  |   16.82 | C2       | Chris Evans 
SS09    | B2     | S3     | M4    | 13-May-16 |   17.90 | C1       | Chris Hemsworth 
SS10    | B4     | S1     | M3    | 6-Jun-16  |   16.37 | C3       | Tom Hiddleston
```

Comment: pls insert data into question and not in pictures

Comment: I'm not sure how to format a table effectively in the text editor.

Comment: I cannot open your link to the table.  I'm sure I am not the only one.  Without the ability to see the table, your question is bordering on incomprehensible

Comment: I can see the image, although it would have been better included in the question. you'll have to explain the possible relationships a bit more. Is a session set up before the customer books it? Can multiple customers book into the same session? How does the price vary - is it a combination of movie & date, or what?

Comment: @Haydennull I added the three first lines in an edit for you, to show how it is done. 4 spaces first on the line, then data.

Comment: See the reply I made to Sturgus below. It's a table given as a question independent of anything else so there are no conditions or rules that relate to the table. I'm assuming that any rules are intended to be assumed and justified.

Comment: ok well then the only really uncontroversial thing is what someone else already said - you don't need to store the customer name in there, just the ID. There should be another table of Customers containing the ID and names uniquely

Comment: or you can go and point out to the teacher that the question is ambiguous :-)

Comment: Added the table to the question. Thank you Linkan.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like this table is in pretty good shape (assuming it's supposed to be a table describing the 'Session').  The only redundant column I see is "customer name", but everything else appears to be necessary.  'Session Price' may or may not be a calculated column (based on the other columns).

Without knowing the business logic, I can't confirm whether or not the 'branch' (or other things) needs to be in there or not.

Edit:
Hypothetically, you could remove the 'session id' column as the pk and add a compound key instead (e.g.: branch + screen + movie + session date + customer id), but that won't necessarily make it better.  Instead, a uniqueness constraint on those columns may be preferred.

Comment: It's a table by itself given as a question for my homework so I cant give any information about business rules or logic. I had a feeling that it was already optimized but it looks nothing like the other examples I've done so I wasn't sure.

Comment: @Haydennull, don't let  a class example get in the way of learning. 100% of the time in the real world you need to understand the business rules.

Comment: If it's for homework, then advise to blow away 'customer name'.  That's probably what they're looking for.